# Split into separate fields an input text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, split

I'm having a trouble when i try to force the user to enter data to a text input. I need to do something like the IP Address input in Windows. [image: Ip Adress Input]

I want to split the text input by dashes having something like this
10 - 10 - 10 - 10

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: you should use some javascript: on keyup event you can check how many chars there are in the input field and add dots or dashes accordingly. Is javascript/jquery an option?

Comment: Yes, of course it's an option. I have not found anything on the web for doing it.

Comment: check out http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ for a javascript library that handles such input cases quite nicely

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/87dug9oa/1/

```
function check(text) {
    var result = [];
    text = text.replace(/[^\d]/g,"");
    while (text.length >= 3) {
        result.push(text.substring(0, 3));
        text = text.substring(3);
    }
    if(text.length > 0) result.push(text);
    $("#ip").val(result.join("-"));
}

$("#ip").on("keyup", function() {
    check($(this).val());
});
```

This creates a function, which adds dashes once 3 characters has been added (and the fourth is written).

Now, this does do what you want, but you need to add some additional stuff, such as checking for length and making the remove part work (because when you press any key, it will change the input's value, which will make the caret move to the last character).

Oh I almost forgot. This can be changed to the length of your choice, of course. Just change the "3" to be something else.

Comment: Your function is awesome, thanks for making it, i need a few reputations points for voting up your answer.

Comment: No problem! It's okay haha. You can always mark it as an answer!